# duplicating current line, and add something to it

Tags: json, eclipse

In eclipse Ctrl + Alt + down copies current line to a new line below. When i do this in a json file, for example, if i use ctrl + alt + down on the last line,
a comma should be added to the current line (as it will no more be the last line of the block). Is there any tool that does this.

Ex 1:

```
{ 
  "employee": {
    "firstName":"John",   ---- line 1
    "lastName":"Doe"       ---- line 2
   }
}
```

If i want to copy line --  "lastName":"Doe"
a comma should be added to the end of line 2 as it will no more be the last line of the block.

Ex 2:

```
{ 
  "employee": {
  "firstName":"John", 
  "lastName":"Doe"
  }
}
```

If i use similar command on the line -- "employee": {
a new employee block should be created after the end of the current block.

Please suggest if there is any tool or eclipse plugin that can do something like this.